# Two BackboneJS fetches and data gets swapped

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, promise, marionette

This is our code inside a single function. I'm just beginning to get better with BackboneJS.

```
// let's pull desktop data
this.desktop = new desktopItemModel({device: 'desktop'});
this.desktopPromise = this.desktop.fetch();

// let's pull mobile data
this.mobile = new mobileItemModel({device: 'mobile'});
this.mobilePromise = this.mobile.fetch();

// I'm not sure if the previous developer was trying to implement similar to $q.all
this.allPromise = [desktopPromise, mobilePromise];

$.when(this.desktopPromise).done(_.bind(function() {
   // do your desktop stuff
}, this));
$.when(this.mobilePromise).done(_.bind(function() {
   // do your mobile stuff
}, this));

if (this.allPromise) {
  $.when.apply($, this.allPromise).done(_.bind(function() {
    // do your stuff here if desktop
    ....
    // do your stuff here if mobile
    ....
  }, this));
}
```

I noticed that there are times that our data in our variable gets mixed up between desktop and mobile. The response from the api server is fine. I actually suspected that the API team was returning us wrong data until I debugged our app, it was our code that was doing something weird.

How can this be refactored so that data doesn't get mixed up? Someone told me in irc, "promises have weird behaviors".

Comment: Can you please describe actual problem with your data? What is mixing? This code slightly defines the order of code execution - third part will not definitely be the first. Promises not weird, they are cool :)

Comment: When the this. mobilePromise is done, we call another function to get more information that is needed for mobile. However, I was wondering why attributes value were from desktopPromise. I added a breakpoint inside the .done of this.mobilePromise. It doesn't happen often but it happens.

Comment: Probably the third block can sometimes run before second one. Do you have any data changing logic in this third one? I will continue in answer to provide some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's rewrite this a little

```
this.desktop = new desktopItemModel({device: 'desktop'});
this.desktopPromise = this.desktop.fetch()
    .then(function(){
        // do your desktop stuff
    }.bind(this));


this.mobile = new mobileItemModel({device: 'mobile'});
this.mobilePromise = this.mobile.fetch()
    .then(function(){
        // do your mobile stuff
    }.bind(this))

$.when(this.desktopPromise, this.mobilePromise)
    .done(function() {
        // do your stuff here if desktop
        // do your stuff here if mobile
    }.bind(this));
}
```

Try this. `Done` will be runned after the promises will be resolved. You can return another promise form "do your mobile stuff" section to delay execution of third section like that:

```
this.mobilePromise = this.mobile.fetch()
    .then(function(){
        // do your mobile stuff
        var moreMobileDetails = new MoreMobileDetails();
        return moreMobileDetails.fetch();
    }.bind(this))
```